# Minecraft Constructs Armory mod - Recover from Parasitic modifier

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-tinkers-construct, minecraft-skyfactory

(Playing Sky Factory 4, if that matters)

I made a set of armor using the Construct Armory, a Tinkers' sub-mod.

I thought that the Parasitic modifier would be good to put on my armor to keep it from breaking.

Parasitic consumes food to repair armor.

But it consumes food way faster than I expected. Every time I get hit, it becomes basically impossible to keep my health and food up and I'm burning through food. My stockpile of food isn't that much of an issue so much as just constantly having to eat and needing stacks of food any time I go somewhere.

The armor is currently Adept and I don't really want to start over (Though, I will accept that answer if it is the only option).

I considered Leveling up the armor enough that I could make it unbreakable, but that seems worse than starting over.

How can I mitigate or remove this problem?

Note: I tried adding Pig Iron for the Tasty effect to eat the armor when hungry and that only made things worse.

Comment: I'm pretty sure SkyFactory has some ways of never having to eat again. And you can probably also unenchant something (if this is even an enchantment, I don't know).

Comment: @FabianRöling I don't know those ways, if they exist. And they're Armory Modifiers, not enchantments.

Comment: Personal nanobot beacon from Environmental Tech, with saturation modifier provides infinite saturation. It must remain chunkloaded to remain in effect to the owner. Not sure if Sky Factory has it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Become an android thru matter overdrive you can then modify yourself at the android table to not need food. Then you have free self repairs on the armor. Note that you do need some power generation capability since you will be an android running off power.

Comment: I believe the Yogscast Sky Factory series shows this off, once they transform themselves into androids. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZqVjrfhHp6o&list=PLGN8WikMb4WGtMra7j3fCfswGnmdByEEA